# While importing from csv file, which format of DateTime is acceptable in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, datetime

I need to import, via comma separated values, data in SQL server.

Here is a sample line

```
37;3.90;13;3.25;14;1.70;0;1;0-1;2;3;1;3-1;1;29/1/2000 5:00:00 μμ;
```

If i am not mistaken, the last field `29/1/2000 5:00:00 μμ` is not acceptable, since it contains culture data.

The specific field is created like so

```
  row += $"{v.KickOff.ToString()};";
```

where `KickOff` is `DateTime` datatype.

Is it ok, or i will have issues later while importing?

Comment: How do you import that CSV file? Do you use BulkCopy or some kind of CSV parser?

Comment: Never use `mm/dd/yyyy` as a date representation for data exchange purposes (in fact, never use `mm/dd/yyyy` for anything, because it's stupid - but that's a different matter). Use `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @Steve I will use the import process of sql management studio

Comment: Furthermore, never build CSV by string concatenation. CSV is too complex for that except in the most basic situations. I'm wondering, if you program C# why don't you write the data directly to the database? Converting it to CSV first is quite a step back here.

Comment: My second comment? What is there to "check out"? Why are you using a different method of importing data in production? If that's so, what's the point of doing it with CSV now? What's the point of doing it with CSV *at all* when you are in C# anyway and can write to the database directly? I don't understand this entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ended up here

```
row += $"{v.KickOff.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")};";
```

I will check this out on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Because you're asking for valid formats of `DateTime` value for SQL, I'm assuming that you're using some sort of a stored procedure to persist data.

Several suggestions:

1. Always try to use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) where ever possible.
2. Use Entity Framework to persist data
3. Parse your values and map to your model (ex: parse your `DateTime` value from your CSV and map to the `DateTime` property of your entity)

Example

```
// 2017-10-28T01:48:04.2399705-07:00
var local = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");

// 2017-10-28T08:51:10.1058821Z
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert this format to time-span format  by using this code
use timeOfDay  format to get date want to convert it into timespan it convert whole date time into interger that is easiest way to insert it into mysql.

`TimeSpan timeOfday=startTime.TimeOfDay;
 DateTime fullstartDateTime =startDate.Add(timeOfday);`